# Multiple trigger-overlays

Tags: jquery, html, css

for some reason, when I click on an image to trigger the overlay it works, but it doesn't work for any of the other id's.

code:

```
<div id="trigger-overlay">
   <div class="portfolio web" data-cat="web">
    <div id="trigger-overlay" class="portfolio-wrapper">            
        <div class="trans">
          <div class="item-info">
            <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
            <h3>Bookworm</h3>
            <span>Books</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`trigger-overlay` is mainly what I'm doing. Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/NLPrF/

When you click the first image it works, but on the second one it doesn't.. Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't edit those scripts because you are pulling them in externally but I can say this.
The script is referencing the images with the selector

```
$("#trigger-overlay").click(function(e)....
```

However, the way the HTML DOM spec works is that theoretically only one element can be assigned a specific ID (ID's are supposed to be unique).

The way I get around this is by using the class attribute as the selector.  Change all your div's to have the class "trigger-overlay"

```
class="trigger-overlay"
```

And change the bit in the javascript that references the ID and change it too

```
$(".trigger-overlay").click(function(e).....
```

The "." selector doesn't have to be unique so the click function will call on ANY element matching the selector.  The "." selector indicates a class name.

**Upon reviewing the actual javascript I realised it would be best if I made the changes**

**New code for demo1.js Code is below**

```
(function() {
    var triggerBttn = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' ),
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
        }
    }
    for (x=0;x<triggerBttn.length;x++) {
        triggerBttn[x].addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    }
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9be3/ there is the JSfiddle as a working demo